# Как обновлять информацию через интервал?

Tags: javascript

По клику на кнопку обновляется информация(комментарии) в блоке.
Как сделать чтобы информация в `<div id="custom-area">` обновлялась каждые 5 минут? Ну и конечно чтобы по клику осталась рабочей.

```
<a onclick="custom_reload('custom-area');return false;">обновить</a>


<div id="custom-area">комментарии</div>


function custom_reload(area){
    ShowLoading();
    $.post(window.location.href,{},function(d){
        HideLoading();
        $("#"+area).html($("#"+area,d).html());
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: а с каким параметром нужно будет вызывать? есть только одна _custom-area_ или на странице несколько их и для каждой должно быть добавлено обновление?

Comment: Пока одна, но возможно будет и несколько.

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(custom_reload.bind(your_area), 5*60*1000);
```

Если не ошибаюсь, можно сделать так.

Comment: С оборотами вида "сорян, пацаны", Вам не расположить собеседника. Вне зависимости от страны, это плохой ответ, даже с исправлением на `setInterval` (недостаточно описан).

Comment: Один минус как-то не тянет на "заминусовали"